# What is the difference between std::ifstream::in and std::ios::in? (obviously as an openmode flag for an std::ifstream in C++)

Tags: c++, ifstream

I used SymbolHound to look for ressources on the web comparing the two but couldn't find anything.

Looking for `std::ifstream::in`'s declaration and definition in VS13 brings me to `basic_ifstream`'s. Looking for `std::ios::in`'s brings me to `basic_ios`'s.

It seems `std::ios::in` is more widely used.

Thanks in advance,

Hans

Comment: To my knowledge `std::ios::in` is only useful when using `std::fstream` (which can do both input and output ops), on `std::ifstream`/`std::ofstream` those flags are useless.

Comment: All the openmodes are inherited from the base class `std::ios_base`, so the full name is `std::ios_base::in`. They are exactly the same when used from a base class or derived class.

Comment: "redundant" or "explicit", if not *useless*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are both the same.

`in` is a member of `std::ios_base`. It's therefore also a member of `ios`, `ifstream`, and everything else that derives from `ios_base`.

> It seems `std::ios::in` is more widely used.

Probably because that's the shortest way to name it.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the types, `std::ifstream` is `std::basic_ifstream<char>` and `std::ios` is `std::basic_ios<char>`.

The hierarchy there is:

```
template< 
    class CharT, 
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>
> class basic_ifstream : public std::basic_istream<CharT, Traits>
```

which is:

```
template< 
    class CharT, 
    class Traits = std::char_traits<CharT>
> class basic_istream : virtual public std::basic_ios<CharT, Traits>
```

`std::ios` is a base class of `std::ifstream`, so `std::ifstream::in` is exactly `std::ios::in`.